# How to reset all array elements?

Tags: arrays, rust

This is the shortest I came up with, after extensive googling and studying the sources:

```
let mut buf = [0u8; 200];
for elem in buf.iter_mut() {
    *elem = 0;
}
```

Is there really no way to make this a one-liner, like `buf.set_all(0)`?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code.  You could use `buf.iter_mut().for_each(|x| *x = 0)` instead if you prefer, but I personally wouldn't.

Comment: Coming from higher level languages this seems unnecessarily pedestrian. But I guess `for_each()` is ok.

Comment: Java is the only "higher level language" I can think of that supports something like this without an explicit loop (`Arrays.fill`). Python, for instance, doesn't.

Comment: @trentcl Python's `numpy` has `fill`, as well as C++ `std::fill`.

Comment: @liliscent NumPy's `fill` only works on `ndarray`s, not Python arrays, but sure.

Comment: You caught me, I'm usually on the JVM. Kotlin has `myArray.fill(element: T, fromIndex: Int = 0, toIndex: Int = size)`. Its an incredibly ergonomic language.

Comment: There is an issue for such a feature ([#2067](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/2067)), but not too much discussion.

Comment: Also maybe worth noting is the `T: Clone` bound in DK's answer. That isn't necessary in Java where everything is references that can be copied freely. I don't know about Kotlin, but if it has affine types, I would assume that `fill` in that language also has some kind of restriction. Defining the exact nature of this restriction in Rust is part of the discussion on the issue I linked earlier (`Copy` vs. `Clone`, basically).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there really no way to make this a one-liner, like `buf.set_all(0)`?

Sure you can make it a one-liner...

```
for elem in buf.iter_mut() { *elem = 0; }
```

Okay, okay... if you do this a lot, you can define an extension trait that provides a `set_all` method.

```
trait SetAll {
    type Elem;
    fn set_all(&mut self, value: Self::Elem);
}

impl<T> SetAll for [T] where T: Clone {
    type Elem = T;
    fn set_all(&mut self, value: T) {
        for e in self {
            *e = value.clone();
        }
    }
}
```

But in terms of *just* using what's in the standard library, there's `for_each` (as noted by Sven Marnach):

```
buf.iter_mut().for_each(|x| *x = 0)
```

Comment: As of earlier this year, there's now https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.fill.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply construct a new array and move it into the array you want to change.

```
buf = [0u8; 200];
```

If the compiler is decent, it can optimize out the temporary array and write directly to the target.

Comment: In my example the array size is known, but thats not always the case, e.g. when using `&mut [u8]`.

Comment: @MichaelBöckling You asked about arrays. `[u8]` is a slice, not an array.

Comment: Guess I was imprecise. I'm only starting to come to terms with the Rust type system, its a strange beast.

Answer (score 2):

Update: the `slice::fill` method is now stable [since 1.50](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.fill).

Answer (score 0):

in your scene, this is my solution:

```rust
let mut buf = [1u8; 200];
unsafe {
    std::ptr::write_volatile(&mut buf, [0u8;200]);
}
```

> Is there really no way to make this a one-liner, like buf.set_all(0)?

and you also can do like this:

```rust
struct Buf([u8;200]);
impl Buf {
    fn clear(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            std::ptr::write_volatile(&mut self.0, [0u8;200]);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut buf1 = Buf([1u8; 200]);
    let mut buf2 = Buf([2u8; 200]);
    buf1.clear();
    buf2.clear();
    println!("{}, {}", buf1.0[199], buf2.0[0]);
}
```